# Spring data jpa repository save() not working for ManyToMany

Tags: sql, oracle, many-to-many, spring-data-jpa, join

I get the following exception in my java application.

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
```

Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (USER1.ID_TYPE_TENANT_UNIQUE) violated.

I have a data model set up with ManyToMany association between two tables. There is a JoinTable between the two and I have the entity set up like this.

```
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator( name = "MyEntitySeq", sequenceName = "SQ_ENTITY", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1 )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "MyEntitySeq")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "MY_JOINED_TABLE", 
    joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "e_id", referencedColumnName = "ID")}, 
    inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "inverse_id", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private Set<Attributes> attributes;

}
```

I have a unique constraint on 3 other fields in the entity table and a unique constraint on the attributes table on name,value. When I try to a persist an entity, which has a set of attributes, the repository.save() method fails because of both:
 1. An attribute may already exist in the attribute table and cannot be inserted due to unique constraint (which is what I want. But I still want to create the association with these attributes to the entity)
2. An entity may already exist but the unique constraint is violated. (I want to still insert the attributes which aren't already in the database and create the association with this entity to the attributes).

If these entities/attributes are not in the database, it works fine and spring inserts into all 3 tables, with the joins and everything.

If I do repository.save() on tables with no associations, the save() updates these tables even if I do a save() on the same primary key.

Why doesn't it work in the case of my manytomany?

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you have been able to solve your issue? I might have a related issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this (sorry for my english, im noob to in Spring MVC and Hibernate), i had similars problems, and this points are importants:

1. you need get elements third entity that you want associate to first entity into same transaction.
2. Sure that in your persistence-context-xml you have